# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from external library

Tags: java

I am using the postgresql driver to connect to a sql server with java.
It is contained in a jar file that i downloaded form there website.

```
java -classpath /home/asdf/myProgram;/home/asdf/myProgram/lib/postgresql-9.2-002.jdbc4.jar myMainClass
```

results in an error:
    Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /home/asdf/myProgram/lib/postgresql-9.2-002.jdbc4.jar

the main class is in /home/asdf/myProgram/myMainClas.class

how do i get java to check for that before checking in postgresql-9.2-002.jdbc4.jar

Comment: Are you sure that's *exactly* the command you're using? You're not using `java -jar ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the path "/home/", you're using Linux.
The semi-colon ends your current command and starts a new one.

So, you are effectively typing:

```
java -classpath /home/asdf/myProgram
/home/asdf/myProgram/lib/postgresql-9.2-002.jdbc4.jar myMainClass
```

This probably means you have the jexec service running, which is trying to run the postgres jar.

Use colon instead, or maybe backslash-colon, like so:

```
java -classpath /home/asdf/myProgram\:/home/asdf/myProgram/lib/postgresql-9.2-002.jdbc4.jar myMainClass
```

Comment: I'd also recommend quoting the whole classpath argument in any O.S.

Comment: sweet got it working - on a side note putting it in quotes will also work.  madth3 what do you mean? instead of myMainClass at the end, put /home/asdf/myProgram/myMainClas.class?